# Editing array's items Php

Tags: php, url, conditional-statements

I am trying to edit array's item. I have $links array right below.

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(22) "http://sumiyoshi22.jp/"
  [1]=>
  string(27) "https://www.finecity138.jp/"
  [2]=>
  string(25) "http://www.hirakata-p.jp/"
  [3]=>
  string(24) "http://www.honki-pj.com/"
  [4]=>
  string(55) "http://nishitetsu-sumai.com/centermarkstower/index.html"
  [5]=>
  string(29) "http://senri100.jp/index.html"
}
```

and trying to make it look like this:

```
array(6) {
  [0]=>
  string(29) "http://sumiyoshi22.jp/outline"
  [1]=>
  string(39) "https://www.finecity138.jp/outline.html"
  [2]=>
  string(32) "http://www.hirakata-p.jp/outline"
  [3]=>
  string(31) "http://www.honki-pj.com/outline"
  [4]=>
  string(57) "http://nishitetsu-sumai.com/centermarkstower/outline.html"
  [5]=>
  string(31) "http://senri100.jp/outline"
}
```

I added "/outline", and changed index -> outline. But one more thing I need to delete in this link http://senri100.jp/index.html ".HTML" part.

This is the function I use.

```
 function add($links){
        if (strpos($links, "https://www.finecity138.jp") === 0){
            return $links."outline.html";
        } else if (strpos($links, "outline") === false){
            return $links."outline";
        }

        return $links;
    }

    foreach ($links as $check){
        $replace[] = add($check);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question extension risks becoming a bit too broad, but I'll answer by only considering the sample data provided.  It seems advantageous to have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dMNau))

```
$array = [
    "http://sumiyoshi22.jp/",
    "https://www.finecity138.jp/",
    "http://www.hirakata-p.jp/",
    "http://www.honki-pj.com/",
    "http://nishitetsu-sumai.com/centermarkstower/index.html",
    "http://senri100.jp/index.html"
];

foreach ($array as $url) {
    $parts = parse_url($url);
    $scheme = $parts["scheme"];
    $host = $parts["host"];
    $path = dirname($parts["path"]) ?? '';
    if (in_array($host, ["www.finecity138.jp", "nishitetsu-sumai.com"])) {
        $path .= ($path == "/" ? "" : "/") . "outline.html";
    } else {
        $path .= "outline";
    }
    $output[] = "{$scheme}://{$host}{$path}";
}
var_export($output);
```

Comment: Thank you, for your answer. if you have time could I ask you one more thing? how can I delete "http://senri100.jp/outline.html" in this HTML word.

Comment: Oh, sorry. In the array fifth item is have ".html"  I am trying to delete it. "http://senri100.jp/outline.html" in the same function. is it possible?

Comment: Start from the beginning.  Does your input array look like this?  https://3v4l.org/SCMZl And what do you want it to look like when you are done?  You want to delete the element, or just the end of the string?

Comment: I explained and give the begining of the array in the question. I hope you could understand it.

Comment: @Barbie updated.  To be honest, there are a lot of ways that this can be achieved and modified.  Only after knowing every single possible value, could I confidently write a refined answer.

Comment: Thank you for answer. I checked it as answer. You are right I did it in different way which is, added to function this line.` if (strpos($links, "http://senri100.jp/outline.html") === 0){
                return str_replace("outline.html", "outline","http://senri100.jp/outline.html");` But really thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are **returning** after the first `if` statement.

Simply reorder your clauses.

```
function add($links){
    if (strpos($links, "https://www.finecity138.jp") === 0){
      return $links."outline.html";
    }
    if (strpos($links, "outline") === false){
      return $links."outline";
    }

    return $links;
}
```